# PyQt5: force a specific language translation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to translate into a specific language regardless which language is selected in the app.  I'm trying to NOT change the language of the app so even knowing the app I'm in I don't think would help me.  Below I have an alwaysTranslate() method that I always want to come back with the translated text even when I unload the translator in the app (or in this event I just don't have one).

```
import sys
from os import getcwd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(556, 362)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.label.setText(_translate("Ui_Form", "something"))

    # this is what I want to come back with a local translation
    def alwaysTranslate(self):
        qt_translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
        m_langPath = getcwd()
        qt_translator.load("test.qm", m_langPath)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        print("should NOT be 'something': " + _translate("Ui_Form", "something"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)

    m_langPath = getcwd()
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

    qt_translator.load("test.qm", m_langPath)
    app.installTranslator(qt_translator)
    print("should NOT be 'something': " + _translate("Ui_Form", "something"))

    qt_translator.load("en.qm", m_langPath)
    app.installTranslator(qt_translator)
    print("should be 'something': " + _translate("Ui_Form", "something"))

    ex =  Ui_Form()
    ex.alwaysTranslate()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I my test.ts file looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS><TS version="2.0" language="zh_TW" sourcelanguage="en_US">
<context>
    <name>Ui_Form</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="test.py" line="58"/>
        <source>something</source>
        <translation>matters not</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

and when I run it I get the following

> should NOT be 'something': matters not
>   should be 'something': something
>   should NOT be 'something': something

the last one I want to be 'matters not' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I would have thought this should work:

```
def alwaysTranslate(self):
    qt_translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    m_langPath = getcwd()
    qt_translator.load("test.qm", m_langPath)
    # use local translator
    _translate = qt_translator.translate
    print("should NOT be 'something': " + _translate("Ui_Form", "something"))
```

Comment: Awesome.  So Could I always do this?  What would be the use of the QCoreApplication.translate?

Comment: @Faller. The `QCoreApplication` version searches all the installed translators, and it also does the `%n` replacement.